# Why can't I champfer this edge more?

Tags: bevel

Something is blocking me from extending the champfer more than I can in the images. I'm trying to extend it further but I can't.
What is the problem?

[image]
^ Trying to bevel
[image]
^The edges I want to bevel

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off Clamp Overlap (shortcut: 'C' while in Bevel mode).
This might have something to do with those small vertical edges on the top and bottom part of the circlular edge, so expect unexpected results.